# Closing open db connections opened by content providers in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a scenario where in the same runtime of my app, all of my local databases could be deleted and then recreated with new encryption. Its an edge case but its possible.

The problem is, the system maintains open connections to these databases because they were accessed via content providers, at least that is to my understanding. When I attempt to create / write to new databases in the same runtime after the old ones were deleted, I receive a crash saying the databases are read-only. If I kill the app and reopen they are fine.

I attempted to kill the app manually using `finishAffinity()` but that doesn't actually kill the app at least enough for the system to clean up the database connections.

Is there some way I can force the system to close the open connections to databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database and open a connection in read mode then you are not able to update or add the data in database.
You have to close the database which you opened by uing

```
 db.close();
```

at the end.

Comment: I know how to explicitly close a db. But I am not opening it explicitly anywhere, I am using content providers, and have no reference to any open database in order to close it.

Comment: use **mProvider.shutdown();**